# Password is not being decrypted correctly from MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

I have a login screen and each time the user logs in the password is encrypted in the MySQL database and then validated before being decrypted back to normal and accepted. They system encrypts the data without problems, but when it decrypts it does it incorrectly and does not work.

The format for the encryption is `byte` but the password format in MySQL is `VARCHAR`. I'm assuming this is what is causing the problem. What would be the correct way to format the data types so that the password is decrypted correctly since MySQL does not have a `byte` format?

Here is an example of what is happening:

[image]

The password is Pass123 and the second line in the message dialog shows how the password is decrypted. The top line then shows how the password is decrypted back from MySQL

Here is the coding for this function:

```
try
{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //connection for database
    Connection conn = (Connection)
            //root and username and password for access to the database
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salventri","root","password");
    //create the statement that will be used
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    //executes the statement
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getCat); 

    int user = Integer.parseInt(txtUsername.getText());
    String pwd = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES"); 
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");



    while (rs.next())
    {
        int uname = rs.getInt("username");
        //Username is the coloumn name in the database table 
        String password = rs.getString("password");
        byte [] pass = password.getBytes();
        cipherText = pass;
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];
        int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);
        ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
        String upassword = String.valueOf(ptLength);


        if (user == uname) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "username  " + uname + " Password " + cipherText + "\n password as string " + password);
            //...
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //exception handled
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: You almost always shouldn't encrypt your users' passwords. Instead, you should hash them with PBKDF2 (random salt and many iterations). If you encrypt your users' passwords, then there is a possibility that all other them can be decrypted when you "lose" the database due to a break in.

Comment: Don't do this. See the description for [tag:password-encryption] for why not. These are serious, company-breaking legal issues.

Comment: MySQL probably is able to handle BLOB's. You cannot just store bytes directly into text, you need something like base 64 encoding. But please heed the advice already given to you and don't encrypt your passwords. If you really really have to, don't use DES.